# Map a void (non-returning function) over an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, uigesturerecognizer

Title is self-explanatory, is there any way of mapping, for example, `addGestureRecognizer` over an array of `UIGestureRecognizers`. I've been fiddling around with variations of

```
recognizers.map(MyWebOutlet.addGestureRecognizer)
```

but since built-in map has to return another array in requires a function that returns some kind of value. Should I just wrap `addGestureRecognizer` in another returning function or is the another cleverer way?

Comment: `recognizers.forEach{MyWebOutlet.addGestureRecognizer($0)}`?

Comment: $0 "anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure" apparently. You only need to pass the function name, like `recognizers.forEach(MyWebOutlet.addGestureRecognizer)` 
But thanks heaps, wasn't aware of forEach :)

Comment: I don't see why the closure version wouldn't have worked – but you're right that you can just pass the function in (I usually prefer to write it out as a closure just to be a bit more explicit)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`map` is designed to return an array from another array that has had a given *transformation* applied to it (by transforming each element). Therefore naturally the function that you pass to it has to return the transformed element.

In your case, you're not actually transforming the elements, you just want to use them in an argument of a function. To do this, you can use `forEach`.

```
recognizers.forEach(MyWebOutlet.addGestureRecognizer)
```

Comment: Yea my brain was very flatulent when googling this and I didn't manage to stumble upon `forEach`. I knew map is designed as an array to array function, I just didn't know what term to use except for "mapping" a function over. Thanks again :)